# Auto-Transcode/Compress .mkv to .mp4 on Qnap TS-251+

Tags: video, ffmpeg, dvd, compression, qnap

I rip my DVDs with [MakeMKV](http://www.makemkv.com/) in order to be able to watch them on my TV, as I do not have a DVD-player that supports any output connector that fit into my TV as the TV is relatively new whereas the DVD-player is quite old. (As I only use the rips for my personal entertainment and do not share them there is absolutely no copyright problem).

The problem with the output files is the extreme size as they are the raw data from the disk. Now I would like these files to be compressed into a .mp4 file as soon as they are finished. The problem is that the file is created before everything is in it, so I probably need to write it into a local drive and copy it to its destination later. Then I will copy them to my Qnap NAS TS-251+.

There I want it do be compressed into a much smaller .mp4 file (usually the .mp4s are a sixth of the original size). I found something using ffmpeg, so I just need a script that does this for me. I do not mind to use a Docker machine for it, but I do not know how to do it. I found this:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v -crf 18 -preset veryslow -c:a copy out.mp4` [here](https://superuser.com/questions/933264/getting-the-smallest-video-with-same-quality-how-to-with-ffmpeg).

I also found [this](https://youtu.be/eBTWSnSTWRA) video, so I know it is in theory possible, I just do not know how to realise it.

In case you ask why I want to use the Qnap NAS, it allows hardware acceleration, whereas my laptop does not.

Comment: I already asked for help on this topic on StackOverFlow, but there it was closed because somebody found it was not on topic and I should post it here. Nevertheless I am looking for some kind of script to automate the process.

Comment: are you running this ffmpeg command on the NAS itself? Bear in mind that hardware transcoders have worse quality than software ones and as such are usually intended for "on the fly" transcoding from higher quality masters. I have a similar setup to you but I leave the files as relatively large MKV files so as to avoid [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss) and let the media server software (Plex) do the transcoding for clients that actually need it.

Comment: The problem is that I have so many DVDs I want to put on the NAS that it would take up more storage than I have. So I searched for a way to comress them down a bit without loosing too much of the quality. And yes, I tought that I could run the command to do so directly on the NAS so it can work 24/7 while I use my laptop for my everyday work where I need all of the processing power I can get (I'm running Simulation and CAD software). So you say I should use software encoding instead? And if I do so, do you think the NAS can handle it, or would you rather do it on the laptop over night?